# Android encode animated webp

Tags: android, webp, encoder

I tried many things so far, is here anyone who knows how I can encode a animated webp file?

I tried to rename a gif into a webp file (sometimes this helps) but that doesn't convert it. I need a real animated webp file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you do? Do you try to convert a series of static images into WebP using Android?

Comment: Yes that's working but I don't know how I can create a animated webp out of it

Comment: Probably you should ask developers of these tools. I think, there are no libraries to create animated WebP still.

Comment: Use ImageMagick, ffmpege, or look for wrapper from libwebp or libvips these two can manipulate the animated webp.

Comment: if someone knows how to deal wtih ndk jni stuff then they would achieve this easily for their project beacuse libwebp, gif2webp, img2webp, cwebp, dwebp are there to manipulate animated webp and convert other formats into webp.

Well i found some libraries you can try any of them.

https://github.com/b4rtaz/android-webp-encoder |
https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper |
https://github.com/zakgof/webp4j